# Java: class error while compiling

Tags: java

that's my first script I write in Java. I get errors while compiling the script. I'd like to know what's wrong with it.

```
public class Main {
    package com.omt.mouse;

    import java.awt.Robot;
    import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            mouseDown = true;
        }
    }


    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            mouseDown = false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Robot robot = new Robot();
        num = 0;
        while (true) {
            if (mouseDown) {
                if (num == 2000) {
                    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                } else {
                    num++;
                }
            } else if (num == 2000) {
                num = 0;
                robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This code is supposed to hold left click after holding it two seconds until pressing again.

Thanks

Comment: Move your package declaration outside of your class declaration, and move your imports beneath your package declaration.  That's all there is to it; this is just a typo.

Comment: By the way, the errors should have given you a clue of what is wrong with your code

Answer (score 0):

This code will be compiled but of course you should start reading compile errors to resolve such issues.

```
package com.omt.mouse;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class Main {
    static boolean mouseDown;
    static int num;

    public static void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            mouseDown = true;
        }
    }


    public static void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            mouseDown = false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {

        Robot robot = new Robot();
        num = 0;
        while(true) {
            if(mouseDown) {
                if(num == 2000) {
                    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                } else {
                    num++;
                }
            } else if (num == 2000) {
                num = 0;
                robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            }
        }

    }
}
```